# running a sudo command from supervisord with the '-E' switch

Tags: python, supervisord

I am trying to run a python application from supervisord and it works except that when you run a command with `sudo` it doesn't have the environmental variables. If I run the command manually I can use the `-E` switch to include the environmental variables in the sudo command.  This works fine, but when I put the command in my supervisord.conf my application can't find the environmental variable. any ideas?

Comment: which environment variables?  Where do they come from in the first place?

Comment: an `export` statement. I've tried doing the export manually and it's in my /etc/bash.bashrc file. I'm in ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to use the `sudo` program from inside `supervisord`, supervisord can already set the correct `uid` for each process, using the `user` paramenter in the `[program:x]` section.  supervisord also takes care of setting the correct environment for each process group using the `environment` option in the same section.  For a pretty concise example of exactly this, see the config in this bit of documentation: http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment